# Clean install of Strapi with existing database - can the content types be restored?

Tags: strapi

I am currently trying to install a fresh install of Strapi against an existing database that was populated some time ago. Whilst I have been able to build a new project that points to the existing database using 'strapi new new-project-name' and can regenerate the API through 'strapi generate:api exampletype', I have found that the Content Types and the content editors do not regenerate in the admin area. Is this a supported scenario of Strapi please or is there a package that can be used to perform this task?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a package that can do this automatically, you can use the strapi generate command as you stated and move over each `model.settings.json` from the old project.

Content-types are not stored in the database, they are defined by those settings files.

Comment: Thank you for your help and knowledge Derrick, restoring those model settings files for each API solved the issue I had encountered.